# Nginx server return duplicate intermediate cert when enable both ECC and RSA cert in Nginx

Tags: ssl, certificate, nginx, rsa, ecc

I have configured Nginx to support both ECC and RSA cert in a hybrid mode.

After enabling, used below cmd to get the full chain cert from my server:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server:443 -servername server-sni
```

Then I got three cert, one leaf, two duplicate intermediate cert (should be only one intermediate cert).

I didn't find any issue with my nginx config

```
    #rsa
    ssl_certificate /path/server_rsa-cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/server_rsa-key.pem;
    # ecc
    ssl_certificate /path/server_ecc-cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/server_ecc-key.pem;
```

Then I tried remove ECC cert or RSA cert, ran openssl command, there is no duplicate intermediate cert after that.

So it seems the duplicate intermediate cert only happen when Nginx in a hybrid cert mode.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after digging around, I have figured out that all these problems are caused by old libressl version I have used. Upgrade libressl version to 2.9.2, then compile Nginx fixed this problem.